# How to keep product table updated

Tags: sql, postgresql, cartesian-product

I have three tables: Table1(A, B), Table2(C, D) and Table3(A, B, C, D).
Table3 contains a Cartesian product of Table1 and Table2.

I need to make the necessary triggers so that whenever I insert, update or delete any rows from Table1 or Table2, Table3 is updated accordingly so that it remains the Cartesian product of Table1 and Table2.

I can't find a reasonable way to do this and I'd appreciate any input.
I'm using PostgreSQL.

EDIT: This is from a past exam, so alternative solutions (such as making Table3 into a view) are not valid.

Comment: Is turning Table3 into a view a viable solution?

Comment: No, it isn't. See edit

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make it a view?

```
CREATE VIEW Table3 AS SELECT A, B, C, D FROM Table1, Table2;
```

That way it will *automatically* stay in sync.

Comment: It will not *automatically* stay in sync. You need to call `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` manually.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OK didn't know that - I assumed it refreshed automatically like Oracle does.

Comment: That would be the logical solution, but it's a question from a past exam so I have to do it as specified

Comment: @user3146897 OK that explains the bizarre scenario :).   Probably would help to explain that in the question so you don't get alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a regular view in current postgres versions, materialized views currently need full reload after base table update. Probably future versions will support incremental updates but full reload is not a very useful feature because it is as trivial as INSERT from SELECT anyways.
It is possible to implement incremental materialized views using triggers but I do not think it is a good idea too because it will be very complicated (you will have to maintain  special tables to store change log )

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sort out the syntax, but the logic is not too dreadful:

- On INSERT into Table1 (new values `new_A`, `new_B`), you need an INSERT like this in the body of the trigger:

  ```
  INSERT INTO Table3 SELECT new_A, new_B, Table2.C, Table2.D FROM Table2
  ```
- Symmetrically, on INSERT into Table2 (new values `new_C`, `new_D`), you need an INSERT like this in the body of the trigger:

  ```
  INSERT INTO Table3 SELECT Table1.A, Table1.B, new_C, new_D FROM Table1
  ```
- On DELETE from Table1 (old values `old_A`, `old_B`), you need a DELETE like this in the body of the trigger:

  ```
  DELETE FROM Table3 WHERE Table3.A = old_A AND Table3.B = old_B
  ```
- And symmetrically, on DELETE from Table2 (old values `old_C`, `old_D`), you need a DELETE like this in the body of the trigger:

  ```
  DELETE FROM Table3 WHERE Table3.C = old_C AND Table3.D = old_D
  ```
- On UPDATE, you can track the old and new values, and execute a DELETE and then an INSERT combination like those above.  You might be able to 'optimize' by looking at whether the update in Table1 changed column A or column B or both, but it probably isn't worth the effort.

I take it back; the logic is dreadful.  It isn't particularly complicated, but the idea of maintaining Table3 like this should make your skin crawl.